# Quote not correctly converted to order: sales_flat_order_item - parent_item_id issue

Tags: magento

When I put a configurable product into the bascet, the configurable product and his simple child are put into the sales_flat_quote_item table with the correct parent_item_id’s.

After converting to order, the items are saved in the sales_flat_order_item table - but the parent_item_id of the simple product is "null" and so it does not point to the configurable product.

This only happens, if one product has been removed from the bascet and another (or the same) was added after that. If a product was added and has been purchased "one way" everything works fine.

What I've done today:
I disabled all local modules.
I disabled all community modules.
I use the default theme.

Does anyone has the same issue sometimes and/or can give me an approach?

(Magento CE 1.6.0.0

Comment: Can you duplicate the issue on a clean install of 1.6.0.0?

Comment: No, on a clean install everything works fine.

Comment: Run a diff against the clean install to see if any core files changed. Another idea is to try the database repair tool from the magentocommerce site.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but for me the problem is that the `parent_item_id` have a wrong product id. This situation have effect if you want to make any change in the order. 
When i try to change the state of the order or make invoice / ship, i have a fatal error.

```
Fatal error Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php on line 441
```

To fix this issue (so i can update the orders) i manual edit the table `sales_flat_order_item`  and i empty the `parent_item_id` from the order have the issue.

This temporary fix... i hope it can help some one....